# Remove unwanted leading slash from nginx

Tags: python, nginx

I have the following config (inside the server tag) for my nginx server:

```
location / {

  proxy_set_header        Host $host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

  # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
  proxy_pass          http://localhost:5000;
  proxy_read_timeout  90;


}
location /api {
  proxy_set_header        Host $host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

  # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
  proxy_pass          http://localhost:2233/;
  proxy_read_timeout  90;
  proxy_redirect default;
}
```

I now try to access /api/auth/login/ via my webbrowser. At port 2233 I have a python server with Flask running. Now in the python console i get:

```
"GET //auth/login/ HTTP/1.0" 404 -
```

In my oppinion this path is messy and also not configured in flask, thats why there is a 404 response (for /auth/login i have a route).

How do I get rid of the leading slash nginx produces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the `proxy_pass` directive to alias `/api/foo` to `/foo`. Alias tends to work best if both source and target URIs end with a `/` or neither end with a `/`.

So:

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:2233/;
    ...
}
```

Will correctly map `/api/foo` to `/foo` without adding the double-`/` at the beginning. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

This may also mean that the bare URI `/api` may not work correctly now.

Alternatively, perform the alias using `rewrite ... break;` instead of `proxy_pass`:

```
location /api {
    rewrite ^/api(?:/(.*))?$ /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:2233;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.